# Find the numbers and calculate output

Tags: code-golf, math

## Objective

Given an input list of `6` distinct digits, find 3 numbers `a`, `b` and `c` such that `a × b = c`, with `a` having 2 digits, `b` having 1 digit and `c` having 3 digits. In a more visual way, your program must arrange those 6 digits in the boxes of this image:

[image]

If more than one solution exists, you may output any of them.

## Input

6 distinct digits. You may take them in any reasonable way for your language.

## Output

The 3 numbers `a`, `b` and `c`. The output format is relatively free, as long as the 3 numbers are separated and are always printed in the same order (but not necessarily in the order `a, b, c`).

## Test Cases

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 -> 54,3,162  
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 -> 57,6,342 or 52,7,364
```

## Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: That's the first thing I thought off when I saw the challenge too @Dada... I suggest putting it in the sandbox to get some feedback before posting it :-)

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to result in a solution?

Comment: I have edited the wording of your challenge quite a bit to make it clear (in my opinion). Make sure I didn't change the goal of the challenge.

Comment: I also think the challenge needs a more explicit title, but I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: Title suggestion: _Arithmetically splitting_

Comment: I guess I'm not surprised that there are no backtracking algorithms here but I am a little sad.

Comment: Should an input of `0,1,2,3,4,5` result in `13,4,052`; no solution; or is any behaviour OK?

Comment: If multiple solutions exist, may the program output *all* of them?

Comment: Just to extend @JonathanAllan point: should we consider the set of digits `[0 .. 9]` or `[1 .. 9]`? Fun fact: my code claims that `14*3==052`. Which is true ... if you read `052` as `42` in octal, like JS does (unless it runs in strict mode).

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>90</s> 88 bytes

Takes input as an array of 6 digits. Returns a string describing a possible solution (such as `'54*3==162'`) or exits with a 'too much recursion' error if (and only if) there's no solution.

```js
f=(a,k=1)=>eval(s='01*2==345'.replace(/\d/g,n=>a[n],a.sort(_=>(k=k*2%3779)&2)))?s:f(a,k)
```

#### How it works

This is a deterministic algorithm.

The primes `P=2` and `Q=3779` were chosen in such a way that the sort callback `(k = k * P % Q) & 2` is guaranteed to generate all 720 possible permutations of the input array over time. More precisely, all permutations are covered after 2798 sorts -- which should be within the recursion limit of all browsers.

We inject each permutation in the expression `01*2==345` by mapping the digits to the corresponding entries in the array.

We evaluate this expression and do recursive calls until it's true.

#### Test

```js
f=(a,k=1)=>eval(s='01*2==345'.replace(/\d/g,n=>a[n],a.sort(_=>(k=k*2%3779)&2)))?s:f(a,k)

console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5,6])); // 54*3==162
console.log(f([2,3,4,5,6,7])); // 52*7==364
console.log(f([1,2,3,4,6,7])); // 73*2==146
```

Comment: Assuming the output format is still valid, use `-` instead of `==` (and reverse the `?:`) to save a byte.

Comment: @Neil Actually, I made the same suggestion to zeppelin. I probably should golf it some more as well, but I must admit that I like the current output format.

Comment: Did you bruteforce to find 3379, or did you use mathematical reasoning? If so, could provide your way of finding it? :)

Comment: @TuukkaX Nothing really fancy here. I just bruteforced it, my criteria being 1) as few digits as possible for P and Q and 2) as few sort iterations as possible.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 10 bytes

```
p~c₃o.k×~t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@19Ql/yoqTlfL/vw9LqS///NjIz/RwEA)

Far too slow to run in a reasonable length of time (the Brachylog interpreter spends a long time doing multiplications on empty strings, 4-digit numbers, negative numbers etc. using a very slow constraint solver). The TIO link uses an input with only 3 digits (this program can handle input with any number of digits). This is a function whose input is a number containing all the digits required (e.g. `234567`) – the lack of duplicates in the input means that you can always just put any `0` at the end to avoid a leading zero – and whose output is a list in the order `[b, a, c]` (e.g. `[6, 57, 342]`).

### Explanation

```
p~c₃o.k×~t
p           Permute the digits of the input
 ~c₃        Split them into three groups
    o       Sort the three groups
     .      to produce the output, which must have the following property:
      k     all but the last group
       ×    when multiplied together
        ~t  produces the last group
```

So where did the requirement on the groups to be 2, 1, and 3 digits go? Well, we know there are 6 digits in the input, and the groups are in sorted orders. The only possible sizes they can have, therefore, are [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3], or [2, 2, 2]. The first case is impossible (you can't multiply two 1-digit numbers to produce a 4-digit number, as 9×9 is only 81), as is the last case (you can't multiply two 2-digit numbers to produce a 2-digit number, as even 10×10 produces 100). Thus, the return values `[b, a, c]` must be 1, 2, and 3 digits long in that order, so `a` is 2 digits, `b` is 1 digit, and `c` is 3 digits, as requested.

Comment: Well...I surrender

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
p~c[Ċ,I,Ṫ]cᵐ.k×~t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@19Qlxx9pEvHU@fhzlWxyQ@3TtDLPjy9ruT//2gjHWMdEx1THTMd89j/UQA)

#### Explanation

```
p                   Try a permutation of the Input
 ~c[Ċ,I,Ṫ]          Deconcatenate it; the result must be a list of the form [[_,_],_,[_,_,_]]
          cᵐ.       Output is the list of integers you get when mapping concatenate on the
                      previous list
             k×~t   The first two ints of the Output, when multiplied, result in the third
                      int of the Output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

Saved two bytes thanks to *Emigna*!

```
œJvy3L£Â`*Qi,
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390sldZpbHPocWHmxK0AjN1/v@PNtJRMNZRMNFRMNVRMNNRMI8FAA)

Explanation:

```
œ                 # Get all permutations of the input
 J                # Join them to get the numbers
  vy              # For each element in the list..
    3L            #   Push the list [1, 2, 3]
      £           #   Pops a and pushes [a[0:1], a[1:3], a[3:6]]
       Â`         #   Bifurcate and flatten
         *        #   Multiply the top two elements in the stack
          Qi      #   If equal to the third element..
            ,     #     Print the array
```

Comment: You can replace `213S` with `3L` as the order didn't have to be `2,1,3` according to the specs.

Comment: Good to know that `£` cumulatively vectorizes... If that's the correct way to say that.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + coreutils, 70

```bash
for((b=1;b;));{
a=`shuf -ze $@`
b=${a:0:2}*${a:2:1}-${a:3:3}
}
echo $b
```

No particularly easy way to generate all the permutations.  Instead randomly generate permutations and calculate until we find a good one.

Output is in the form `A*B-C` - i.e. the expression that will evaluate to zero when we have the correct permutation.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6ShkWRraJ1kralpXc2VaJtQnFGapqBblaqg4pDAlWSrUp1oZWBlVKsFYhhZGdbqghjGVsa1XLVcqckZ@QoqSf///zdSMFYwUTBVMFMw/5qXr5ucmJyRCgA).

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
qm!{3/)2/+:i}%{(\:*=}=p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@Yq1htrK9ppK9tlVmrWq0RY6VlW2tb8P@/oZGxiakZAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 105 bytes

```python
lambda s:[(x[0],x[1:3],x[3:])for x in permutations(s)if eval('%s*%s%s==%s%s%s'%x)]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcVLCsMgEADQfU8xG1FDF23TDwiexLqwNMJAdMSZFG@fks172b/3NZXPNwG7YEa4xPMIVzcfzS7aTB0GYIW29LJJEqTKhi1mWH5pNVrxpFix94eKtRo2nnKnAihLF6KVAUujLtPeOlYx2WBtmxhr7a5v8/3xfOk/)

## 88 bytes solution with a more *flexible* output

```python
lambda s:[x for x in permutations(s)if eval('%s*%s%s==%s%s%s'%x)]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcRLCgMhDADQfU@RjWhm2S8UPEnbhaUKATWSZIq3t/QtXonPVVN7fxLo/TGhsMAE6jCytN2SEXcNilQgf1MN3unm1GmM/516N/F1KMINyLIYc1WgNlhsW0OoWyiB@tgtIOLyx9P5cr35Hw)
where the output would be ['6', '5', '7', '3', '4', '2'] instead '6', '57', '342'

Comment: You didn't put your `import` at the top... *shakes head*

Comment: @mbomb007 gotta work on TIO ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You're the first person I've seen who actually put the `f=` in the header. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 110 bytes

It'll get there... eventually...

```
<?$v=$argv;unset($v[0]);do shuffle($v)&[$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f]=$v;while("$a$b"*$c!="$d$e$f");echo"$a$b $c $d$e$f";
```

Ungolfed:

```
<?
$v=$argv;
unset($v[0]);
do
  shuffle($v);
  [$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f]=$v;
while("$a$b"*$c!="$d$e$f");
echo"$a$b $c $d$e$f";
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 77 bytes

```
for(;;)eval(strtr('0.*1-"428"||die("0.,1,428");',1/7,str_shuffle($argv[1])));
```

Takes input as a string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

17 bytes of code, +1 for `-S` flag.

```
$/_=1FI_^@3,5MPMa
```

Takes input as a string of digits via command-line argument. Output is in the order c, b, a. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@6@iH29r6OYZH@dgrGPqG@Cb@P//fyNjE1Mz8/@6wQA)

This code outputs *all* solutions if multiple exist. If it is required to output only *one* solution, then add three bytes and wrap the program in `(...0)`.

#### Explanation

```
                   a is 1st cmdline arg (implicit)
              PMa  Compute all permutations of a
             M     To each, map this function:
          3,5       Range(3,5)--contains values 3 and 4
       _^@          Split the function argument at those indices
                    This transforms a string like 342657 into a list [342; 6; 57]
     FI            Now filter the list of split permutations on this function:
$/_                 Fold on division: takes 1st element and divides it by the rest
   =1               Compare the quotient with 1
                    This keeps only the permutations where the first number is the product
                    of the other two
                   Autoprint the list (implicit), with each sublist on a separate line
                   and space-separated (-S flag)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 60 bytes

```
->x{x.permutation{|a|(eval a="%d%d*%d==%d%d%d"%a)&&puts(a)}}
```

Prints all solutions as "a*b==c"

#### Example:

```
->x{x.permutation{|a|(eval a="%d%d*%d==%d%d%d"%a)&&puts(a)}}[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
54*3==162

->x{x.permutation{|a|(eval a="%d%d*%d==%d%d%d"%a)&&puts(a)}}[[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
52*7==364
57*6==342
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 (Javascript), <del>85</del>, <del>82</del>, 79 bytes

Accepts an array of digits (strings), returns a 3-element array `[A,B,C]` =>  `C=A*B`

**Golfed**

```js
R=(w,[a,b,c,d,e,f]=w)=>f*(d+=e)^(a+=b+c)?R(w.sort(_=>Math.random()-.5)):[a,d,f]
```

EDITS:

- Saved 3 more bytes by reusing `d` and `a`, and getting rid of `==` (Thanks @Arnauld !)
- Saved 3 bytes using destructuring assignment

**Try It !**

```js
R=(w,[a,b,c,d,e,f]=w)=>f*(d+=e)^(a+=b+c)?R(w.sort(_=>Math.random()-.5)):[a,d,f];

function generate(A) {
   console.log(R([...A]));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" value="123456"/><button onclick="generate(A.value)">GENERATE</button>
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that your random sort will actually cover all permutations?

Comment: @Neil, if you are looking for strict formal proof, I don't think I can provide you with one, but [empirically](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#ZY69CoMwFIX3PMWhUyQa@oNTmjXgkCcQh9TGGrBJiTqJj93ZpjiVTpfzXe757mZkfcrP@aURqOS5LAW0rBtBSBcidZA4CjhcUaXBWIaFAIaPIU60m307ueCpyW9pgWinOXpoM/U8Gn8PT5oVvMSaiXSk@Wsee2rY4ZDySojeW1IgSi6r2I3y3@c6qmvXwHmo/QGo@ksaxlLzCjuM9ofL05cnSRv8GAbLh/CgKhPb9vahaE3b2w8) it does result in a pretty much uniform distribution of permutations.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 305 bytes

```
@echo off
set/pd=
for /l %%i in (0,1,719)do set n=%%i&call:c
exit/b
:c
set t=%d%
set s=
for /l %%j in (6,-1,1)do set/ap=n%%%%j,n/=%%j&call:l
set s=%s:~0,2%*%s:~2,1%-%s:~3%
set/an=%s%
if %n%==0 echo %s%
exit/b
:l
call set u=%%t:~%p%%%
call set s=%%s%%%%u:~,1%%
call set t=%%t:~,%p%%%%%u:~1%%
```

Takes input on STDIN as a string `[1-9]{6}` and outputs all solutions in `dd*d-ddd` format. Batch isn't very good at string manipulation so generating the 720 permutations is a little awkward.